# should I add a relay for headlight bulb

Tags: electrical, battery, headlight, suzuki, replacements

I own a suzuki gixxer. The [stock configuration](https://www.suzukimotorcycle.co.in/product/gixxer#accordion_menu) of headlight is **12V 35/35W**. Now I've upgraded it to [philips extreme vision](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B010VNEH86) which is **12V 60/55W**. Since the new bulb are 2x watts of stock configuration should I add a relay? I've already researched about this for the past 5 days both online/offline but all I get is answers on both sides.

Comment: Does the bike not have a headlight relay already?  Normally high draw items like the headlight already have a relay.

Comment: I don’t know. I’m unable to find such thing already.

Comment: Well, you could call the parts department of a local Suzuki dealer and ask if your bike has one.  They should have a full parts catalog.  If there is one, see if they can tell you the Amp rating of the relay.

Comment: But both bulbs are 12v? So is external relay needed?

Comment: Maybe you're not sure what a relay does?  A relay is basically a heavy duty switch that can be controlled by a smaller basic switch (simplified explanation).  For instance instead of needing a large switch on the handlebars for the headlights, you could have a small, compact switch that controls a relay that actually switches the high wattage bulbs.  I'm saying the bike _probably_ has a relay already since headlights are already a high-wattage item.

Answer (score 3):

It would be prudent to add a relay as manufacturers have been finding ways to reduce total weight and one method has been to use wires of the minimum thickness for each component.

So, fit a relay and avoid a possible problem and also give the new bulb a better supply as there will be fewer losses.

Comment: another trick could be just put the new bulb in and turn on (not recommended) and see if the headlight fuse blows or wires to headlight becoming warmer. If the fuse blows or wires started getting hotter then you should use a relay with proper amperage

Comment: @Nilabja and when you do that and the wire melts you give me and my other electrician friends lots of expensive work repairing it.... Better to err on the side of caution and fit the relay.

Comment: thats why I said not recommended :P

Comment: not good practise to suggest bad practise... and you only put that - the most important part in parentheses... as if it was not important.

Comment: I do not know how to put that in bold characters

Comment: well putting it in brackets was not the way to go...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66529/discussion-between-nilabja-and-solar-mike).